# Definition of extended euclidean space

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space

My professor told me that the definition of the extended euclidean space (which in my course is denoted by $\mathbb{E}_n^{\star}$) is “needed” to define a projective space, but I can’t see how that could be done. Can’t we define the extended euclidean space as $\mathbb{E}_n^{\star}:=P(\mathbb{E}_{n+1})\cup\Omega$, where $P(V)$ is a projective space over some field and $\Omega$ is the hyperplane at infinity? Am I missing something?

Comment: Stereographic projection is the most common way to do it which for Euclidean spaces is equivalent to the one-point compactification (Alexandroff extension). So we get to enrich the system with a single $\Omega$ rather than requiring more complicated structure. So you're sort of bundling the line into a circle, the plane into a sphere, and so on so that antipodal points are well-defined. In particular you get this nice relationship between $0$ and $\Omega$ where the reciprocation $x \to \frac1x$ swaps them geometrically. The Riemann sphere is instructive to help you build intuition.